# What is the meaning of "flash and brass" in the following context?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

What is the meaning of "flash and brass" in the following context:

> Now that I’m older, I think I can appreciate that more and tap into it a little better than when I was younger. Because back then, I was all **flash and brass**.

it's from an interview which you can find here [John Leguizamo talks *The hollow point John Wick* and Brian-de-Palma](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2016/12/16/john-leguizamo-talks-the-hollow-point-john-wick-and-brian-de-palma)

Comment: This is a quote, but there is no source provided.  Please tell us the book that this quote comes from.

Comment: It's not a book, it's from an interview which you can find here https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2016/12/16/john-leguizamo-talks-the-hollow-point-john-wick-and-brian-de-palma

Comment: I've not seen the collocation before, but it looks a form of "reduplication" where ***flash[y]*** and ***brass[y]*** both mean "tastelessly extravagant" - and by implication, ***shallow, superficial***, which I suspect is the specific sense John Leguizamo had in mind when talking about portraying the "internal" conflicts of a character rather than simple "action / adventure" stuff.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not write an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @JamesK: Because it's either a relatively uncommon AmE usage OR (my guess) effectively a "one-off" usage. I checked Google Books, and they don't have a *single* instance of the sequence ***all flash and brass*** (but there are plenty of collocations that probably mostly have similar meanings: ***all flash and bang / style / glamour / splash / ...***). That's why I think it's a one-off (and if I was *sure*, I'd just closevote).